# ChartJS not working in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chart.js

I have a file named `index.html` in my Chrome extension that uses ChartJS to draw a chart. This is the markup :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" height="400" width="900"></canvas>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is the script:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

I am not getting any error in console. But still, the page is rendered blank. What could be the issue with this code?

Comment: I think you only declare the chart but you don't render it using the context.

Comment: @GiaFil7 I am passing the `ctx` object to the `Chart()` constructor. It should render the chart for me.

Comment: Hi, @AnimeshKumar :D.  It renders (check [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kavepoyeqa/edit?html,css,js,output)), so, my best bet? You are not linking the script right. I saw that first script is in path `scripts/Chart.min.js` while the second one is in `./script.js`, so... are your sure that you don't have this second script also in `scripts/script.js`? If that isn't the case... without a proper jsbin or something like that, where we can check your code live, I don't know. Becaue is clear that the code is working and it renders...

Comment: Made a mistake with the link. Is [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gumuxen/1/edit?html,css,js,output). Sorry.

Comment: @soulchainer Hey Juan :) I also tried running it in Codepen and it is working. But it's not working in my machine. Both the scripts are imported properly (I have `console.log` statements in both the files and they are working). The only issue I maybe having is that the file isn't a simple webpage. It is a webpage inside of a Chrome Extension. And maybe ChartJS (or HTML Canvas) isn't supported in extensions.

Comment: @AnimeshKumar Got your problem figured out, Ani.
Basically, you have an *OLDER* version of Chart in your extension. I mean, version 1.01, from 2015... It doesn't work. If you change it for the minimized version of the most current Chart release, it works.
It's just that. Everything is fine, you just need to use a current version of the library.

Comment: Thanks @soulchainer. That's probably the answer :)